# Getting next line in a file

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am reading in a file and wonder if there's a way to read the next line in a for loop?

I am currently reading the file like this:

```
file = open(input,"r").read()
for line in file.splitlines():
  line = doSomething()
```

So is there anyway I can retrieve the next line of the file in that for loop such that I can perform some operation in the `doSomething()` function?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just loop over the open file:

```
infile = open(input,"r")
for line in infile:
    line = doSomething(line, next(infile))
```

Because you now use the file as an iterator, you can call the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on the `infile` variable at any time to retrieve an extra line.

Two extra tips:

1. Don't call your variable `file`; it masks the built-in `file` type object in python. I named it `infile` instead.
2. You can use the open file as a context manager with the `with` statement. It'll close the file for you automatically when done:

   ```
   with open(input,"r") as infile:
       for line in infile:
           line = doSomething(line, next(infile))
   ```

Comment: this is better than my indexing solution as it actually increments the counter as well...

Comment: @Martijin: A small query: Using `next()` will move the pointer to the next line, but when the control comes back to the for loop, will it again read the "next" line or pass on to the next-to-next line?

Comment: @Konstant: Next to next. Using a `for` loop calls `.next()` as well, and every time you do that a *new* line is returned until the file is done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks a lot. So if i have to read every line in a file and process it depending on the next one, i cannot use it. Right? Just curious (and learning).

Comment: @Martijn: Good advice regarding not naming a variable `file`, but (as I'm sure you know) it also applies to `input`.

Comment: @Konstant: You'd have to use some kind of push-back buffer, yes. Load the next line, push it back into the buffer when done.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to make `next(infile)` skip ahead more than one place? For example, can I get the 'next' `next(infile)` to move the iterator two places ahead, or an arbitrary number of places ahead? I tried `next(next(infile))` but that did not work.

Comment: @user5359531: `next()` always gives you the next item from an iterator. You can insert an [`itertools.islice()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) if you need to skip items and use the next item after that: `next(islice(infile, 2, 3))` skips to, then produces the 3rd.

Answer (score 8):

```
file = open(input,"r").read()
lines =  file.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
     line = lines[i]
     next_line = lines[i+1]
```

Comment: why -1? ... this does what was asked ... Martjin's answer is better granted but this gives you next line (at least now it does .. was missing read() )...

Comment: how do you close the file in this case?

Comment: file.close() ... or understand python garbage collection... or understand that opening a file for reading does not lock the file so it doesnt really matter in general ... you could just as easily use a `with open(...) as f` context if you are really worried about it

Answer (score 8):

I think that you mean that if you are in line n, you want to be able to access line n+1.

The simplest way to do that is to replace

`for line in file.splitlines():`

with

```
lines = file.readlines()
for i in xrange(len(lines)):
```

then you can get the current line with  `lines[i]`  and the next line with  `lines[i+1]`

the more pythonic way is to use enumerate

```
lines = file.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
```

now you have the current line in "line" like normal, but you also have the index if you want to find a different line relative to it.

Comment: Martin posted his answer while I was fighting with the editor. His is a little more svelte, but it's still worthwhile to be aware of the enumerate option.

Comment: Coming across this answer in 2016 it bears pointing out that 'xrange' does not exist in Python 3 and 'range' should be used instead.

Comment: Doesn't this approach read the entire file into memory, in contrast to the method that uses the file as an iterator (`for line in infile:`)? That may be a trivial difference to some, but could matter quite a lot if you are dealing with very large files. The iterator method is inherently more efficient.