# Reading in a text file in a set line range

Tags: python, file

Is it possible to read in from a text file a set line range for example from line 20 to 52?

I am opening the file and reading the file like this:

```
text_file = open(file_to_save, "r")
line = text_file.readline()
```

but only want to save the data in a set range or if it possible to read in from a after a  line containing  --- data --- to another line containing -- end of data --

I have looked through the documentation and online examples and can only find examples that specify a new line or something

Comment: See [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

Comment: Thanks will look at their documentation now

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on the file object and use iteration to read only specific lines:

```
import itertools

with open(file_to_save, "r") as text_file:
    for line in itertools.islice(text_file, 19, 52):
         # do something with line
```

would read lines 20 through to 52; Python uses 0-based indexing, so line 1 is numbered 0.

Using the file object as an iterator gives you a lot of flexibility; you can read extra lines by [calling `next()` on the file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647006/getting-next-line-in-a-file), for example, advancing the line 'pointer' as you do so.

When using the file as an iterable, [*don't* use `readline()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278163/combining-readline-and-for-loop-without-using-next-in-python); the two techniques are not easily mixed.

Comment: If you wanted to read a sample of lines from a file, would you need to read them sequentially?  OR - if you want to read lines 25 and 12, should you read line 12 first?

Comment: @wwii: you can do random access (using `file.seek()`), but then you have to search for the newlines manually, and you can't know the *count* of lines. Unless your file format uses fixed-length lines, it is just way, way easier to read sequentially if you need to read specific lines.

Answer (score 8):

You can do two things. You can use `enumerate()`, and use an `if` statement:

```
text_file = open(file_to_save, "r")
lines = []
for index, text in enumerate(text_file):
    if 19 <= index <= 51:
        lines.append(text)
```

Or instead, you can use `readlines()` and then slice:

```
text_file = open(file_to_save, "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
lines = lines[19:52]
```

Comment: 'readline()' should be 'readlines()' in the second to last line

Answer (score -1):

HM,you can try something with while loop....but you should know up to which string you want text to be loaded,which is not best way:

```
text_file=open(name,'r')
line=text.readline()
while line!=(" ") #type the line where you want it to stop
print (line
```