# Reading every 100 lines (or less) from an open file in Python

Tags: python

I have a file with 100s of thousands of records, one per line. I need to read 100, process them, read another 100, process them and so forth. I don't want to load those many records and keep them in memory. How do I read (until EOF) either 100 or less (when EOF is encountered) lines from an open file using Python?

Comment: please define "record"

Comment: Call `readline()` 100 times... stop calling it if you hit EOF...?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to process them 100 at a time, rather than one at a time, or 64 at a time, or whatever? Is this to do with buffering, or is there something in particular about 100?

Comment: Related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716001/python-reading-in-a-text-file-in-a-set-line-range . The accepted answer seems to fit your needs, with a little tweaking so you can do the 100 first, then 100 others, etc. I don't know the impact on the memory though.

Comment: @DNA: I need to process 100 at a time because I'm using an api with a cap on the number of calls I can make. I can obviously parameterize the value for other APIs.

Comment: Take this!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python

Answer (score 7):

`islice()` can be used to retrieve the next `n` items of an iterator.

```
from itertools import islice

with open(...) as file:
    while True:
        lines = list(islice(file, 100))
        for line in lines:
            # do stuff
        if not lines:
            break
```

Comment: It works well. I would suggest putting the ``if not lines`` before ``do stuff``  to avoid a blank list at the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    workset = [] # start a work set
    for line in f: # iterate over file
        workset.append(line) # add current line to work set
        if len(workset) == 100: # if 100 items in work set,
            dostuff(workset) # send work set to processing
            workset = [] # make a new work set
    if workset: # if there's an unprocessed work set at the end (<100 items),
        dostuff(workset) # process it
```

Answer (score 2):

A runnable example using the `take` recipe from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) page:

```
from itertools import islice

# Recipe from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
     while True:
       lines = take(100, f)
       if lines:
         print(lines)
       else:
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize `i_zip_longest` in the [`grouper` recipe](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.ca/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html), which would also address your EOF issue:

```
with open("my_big_file") as f:
    for chunk_100 in izip_longest(*[f] * 100)
          #record my lines
```

Here we are simply iterating over our file lines, and specifying our fixed-length chunk to be 100 lines.

A simple example of the `grouper` recipe (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file.readlines(sizehint= <line size in Bytes> )
```

instead of creating your own iterator, you can use the built-in one.

python's method `file.readlines()` returns a list of all the lines in the file.
if the file is too big it wont fit in memory.

so, you can use the parameter `sizehint`.
it will read the `sizehint` **Bytes**(and **not lines**) from the file, and enough more to complete a line, and returns the lines from that.

Only complete lines
will be returned.

for example:

```
file.readlines(sizehint=1000)
```

it will read the 1000 Bytes from the file.