# For Loop in python x number of times from a file

Tags: python, for-loop

The script runs for the number of accounts that are present in the accounts.txt file. I want to run the script x number of times, no matter how many accounts are present in the accounts.txt file. So I just enter an input 10 and the script should run the for loop for only 10 times. Below is my code.

Can someone please help me as to how to fix the for loop or add a new parent for the for loop?

```
file = open('accounts.txt','r')

for line in file:
    credentials = line.split(";")
    username = credentials[0]
    password = credentials[1]
    comment = credentials[2]

    chromedriver = "/Users/Ali/Downloads/chromedriver"

    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
   # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
```

Comment: You could use a variable like `x=0` and then `while x < 10:` as your loop as this would loop through 10 times.

Comment: Please post a censored sample of your accounts.txt

Comment: Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to *count* the iterations and stop when you reach your limit with [break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716047/1567255

Comment: myemail@gmail.com;password;comment  <-- this is the format for accounts.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work:

```
for count, line in enumerate(file):
    credentials = line.split(";")
    username = credentials[0]
    password = credentials[1]
    comment = credentials[2]

    chromedriver = "/Users/Ali/Downloads/chromedriver"

    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
   # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

    if count == 9: # count starts at 0
        break
```

Comment: Great i fixed my issue, just needed to convert it into integer after it accepts input.. thanks alot..

Answer (score 0):

Put the reading thing in a function :

```
def run_loop():
    file_han = open('accounts.txt','r')
    file = file_han.read().split('/n') #you need to read and split the file w.r.t lines
    file_han.close()
    for line in file:
        credentials = line.split(";")
        username = credentials[0]
        password = credentials[1]
        comment = credentials[2]

        chromedriver = "/Users/Ali/Downloads/chromedriver"

        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

#Now loop the function over and over
i=0
while i =! input('Enter iterations no:'):
    run_loop()
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to use `itertools.islice()` which allows you to pick exactly as many values from an iterator (e.g a file pointer) that you want:

```
import itertools

with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as file:
    wanted_lines = 10
    for line in itertools.islice(file, wanted_lines):
        credentials = line.split(";")
        username = credentials[0]
        password = credentials[1]
        comment = credentials[2]

        chromedriver = "/Users/Ali/Downloads/chromedriver"

        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
       # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
```

Here, in addition, I have used the `with open...` construction to open the file to read. The benefit of doing this, is that the file will automatically close when reaching the end of the `with` block.