# Reading in and then writing out a selected blocks of awkward text

Tags: python

I have a ascii file with text I need to take from it's current awkward format and create a new file containing the reformatted text.  The input file - "datafile.txt" in my example - contains a series of regularly spaced and structured blocks of text.  I need to extract each block and reformat them to fit a particular ascii interchange standard.

I know the line range for each block - in my example lines **2 to 6** for the first block - and taking an answer here ([Reading in a text file in a set line range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716001/reading-in-a-text-file-in-a-set-line-range)) wrote:

```
filetoread = open("datafile.txt","r")
lines = filetoread.readlines()
lines_pt1 = lines[2:6]

filename = "myfile.txt"
f = open(filename,"w")
f.write(str(lines_pt1))

f.close()
```

This works but I need to do further work to tidy the output string, removing unwanted sets of characters, including new lines "/n" and other character sets plus replace all spaces of length 5 to be of length 1.

It seems I need to work out how to do reformatting with the strings in the list but my attempts have failed so far.  Looking for advice on the best way forward.

Edits:
Example of "datafile.txt":
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8GBO17JqUcdZkhmVVZaNUJwdDA/view?usp=sharing

Example of desired output in "myfile.txt":
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8GBO17JqUcdUER6RnFrWTM1dVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post a sample of your file and your desired output if you were to mutate that file with your ideal program.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - I've added links to the sample input file and desired output example now.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that:

1. you need to remove all leading and trailing spaces/newlines for each line
2. you need to replace a set of exactly 5 spaces with a single space each line

Step 1 can be accomplished `myLine.strip()`, which is a built-in method of any string.

For step 2, you can use the python Regular Expression module, `re`

```
import re
...
line_to_format = '...'
line_to_format = res.sub(r'\s{5}', ' ', line_to_format)
```

(more info in `re` can be found here: [re - docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html))

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('practice_file.txt')]

first_part = [i[5:] for i in f[2:7]]

second_part = [i[5:] for i in f[8:]]

final_data = first_part + second_part

the_file = open('practice_file.txt', 'w')

for i in final_data:
     the_file.write(i+"\n")

the_file.close()
```